# Automatically deploy latest revision to website from SVN server

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm new with SVN and version controlling.

I have a `www` folder where I have to put my `.html` and `.php` files. I made a `svn/repository` folder keeping my versions of what I would like inside the `www` folder.
(For instance, from remote computer, I can "pull" the content of the last version.)

What I would like is to know how I can keep the last version in the `www` folder.

I read about making a local repository, but if I do so, shouldn't I have to update it manually every time I commit changes ?

Thanks for the answers !

Comment: This can be a lot more complicated than that. Do you want every commit to trunk pushed to the server? Only tagged commits? Certain branches? Generally you would want to use `svn export` to deploy (does not have the `.svn` folder), but if the SVN server has access to the www folder, this could be done with a hook.

Comment: The SVN server has access to the www folder.

I'm going to read about hooks then :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want can be done with svn post-update hook

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html

hope this helps